# Mysql priviléges

Tags: mysql, sql

for user boss12 i associate the right to modify only the name, But I want to know how to associate that renaming only the student with idStu = 12, i.e he can change the name of the student (idStu = 12) but he can not for the student (idStu = 13).

```
create database gcr;
use gcr;
create table Student(
      idStu int primary key,
      nom varchar(30),
      moyen real)engine=innodb;
insert into Student values(12,'hassen',15.0);
insert into Student values(13,'ouss',12.0);
create user boss12@localhost
    identified by 'enig';
create user prof@localhost
    identified by 'gcrgcr';
use mysql;
grant select, update,insert on gcr.Student
  to prof@localhost with grant option;
grant update (nom) on gcr.Student
  to boss12@localhost with grant option;
```

Comment: You can use JOINs to control this kind of thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's in French.

Comment: sorry my bad :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible in any straightforward way.
There's no row-level security in the very vast majority of RDBMS.

However, theoretically, you can build the additional level that encapsulates the main dataset + additional row level security data (e.g. table(s) that describes the access grants/policies/restrictions for particular rows + reference to these rules from the main data tables) - and then

But that's quite tricky part, let me tell you - even for reads.
And I'm really not sure is it possible for updates in such a case.

---

The other way is to set a before-update trigger on the given table, then check whatever conditions you want against the requestor's user - and fail the transaction if needed.

But that, honestly, is a dirty hack in your case - heavily data-depending (thus error prone) and hardly maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Direct solution for you question is not available . According to my understanding you want user boss12 should able to update only some data in table Student.

for ex, update Student set nom='' where idstu =12 should work but  update Student set nom='' where idstu =13 should not work .

**This is not possible to control via privilege control You can create view on student table where you want to provide update privilege to user idstu.**

[sql reference for column level privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges)